# Usng variables as column names within a range

Tags: excel, vba

can i have some assistance with the syntax to refer to a an entire row (or column) within a range ?

I know that i can specify a row (row 1) to perform some functions like this:

```
With ws1.Range("1:1")
....
End With
```

How do i specify a row using a variable ? For example

```
With ws1.Range("rowVariable:rowVariable")
...
End With
```

Test Data:

```
freqPlan    freqChan    freq2Update fNote
Narrow81    AB31'       90.111110   N67
Narrow81    B842        99.880000   N68
Narrow81    B842'       99.880000   N68
```

My Code:

```
Sub remFootnote()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheet1

Dim lastRow, Index, i As Integer
Dim freq2Update, freqPlan, freqChan, fNote As String

freq2Update = 99.88
freqPlan = "Narrow82"
freqChan = "B842'"
fNote = "N68"

lastRow = ws1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

   For Index = 2 To lastRow
    i = Index
    If ws1.Range("A" & i).Value = "Narrow81" Then
       If ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = "B842'" Then
          With ws1.Range("i : i")  '**this is the line i have issues with**
             Set d = .Find(fNote, LookIn:=xlValues) 'when fnote is found in Row "i"
             d.ClearContents                        'delete it
          End With
        End If
    End If
   Next Index

 End Sub
```

I have the watch window activated to see my variables and the code above works fine up to the line where i try to execute this line:

```
With ws1.Range("i : i")
```

I have tried the following variations to no avail:

```
With ws1.Range("i : i")
With ws1.Range(i:i)
With ws1.Range(i":"i)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `With ws.Rows(i)`? `With ws.Range(i & ":" & i)`?

Comment: `Dim lastRow, Index, i As Integer` - this line doesn't work the way you think it is. You have to assign the variable type each time. The way you used this actually has `lastRow` & `Index` as variants. You need to use `Dim lastRow as Long, Index as Long, i as Long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A few issues here:

1. Just use `Range.EntireRow`
2. Not sure why you need variables `Index` and `i` - since they are the exact same thing, just use one
3. You need to add `Dim d as Range` to your code. Also, you have to assign variable types each time. The comma seperated method you are using is not correct
4. You need to code for the chance that your value is **not** found in the row you are searching. So, check to make sure your range variable `d` is not `Nothing` before taking any action
5. The better way to find the last row is to go from bottom up (`ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`)

---

*Putting all this together:*

```
'Poper way to declare variables
Dim lastRow as Long, i As Long
Dim freqPlan as String, freqChan as String, fNote As String
Dim freq2Update as Double
Dim d as Range

'Assign variable values here

ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Simplified loop
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If ws1.Range("A" & i) = "Narrow81" And ws1.Range("B" & i) = "B842" Then
        Set d = ws.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Find(fNote, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not d Is Nothing Then d.ClearContents
        Set d = Nothing
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing of

```
With ws1.Range("i : i")  '**this is the line i have issues with**
       Set d = .Find(fNote, LookIn:=xlValues) 'when fnote is found in Row "i"
       d.ClearContents                        'delete it
End With
```

with

```
With ws1.Range(i & ":" & i)  'the string range must be built from the variable concatenated with ":"...
       Set d = .Find(fNote, LookIn:=xlValues) 
       d.ClearContents                        'clears its contents
End With
```

or even simpler, with:

```
With ws1.Rows(i)  
       Set d = .Find(fNote, LookIn:=xlValues) 
       d.ClearContents                        'clears its contents
End With
```